How do I use the arcTo function from the Path API in Jetpack Compose?
I'm trying to create a shape in canvas using jetpack compose but it's not working out.
The shape in question is a rectangle with an half circle arch on the right side.
Here is the code
@Composable
fun MyCanvas() {
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier
        .width(300.dp)
        .height(300.dp)
        ) {
        val path = Path().apply {
            moveTo(400f, 100f)
            lineTo(100f, 100f)
            lineTo(100f, 400f)
            lineTo(600f, 400f)
            arcTo(
                rect = Rect(
                    left = 100f,
                    top = 400f,
                    right = 600f,
                    bottom = 400f
                )
                , startAngleDegrees = 0f,
                sweepAngleDegrees = 90f,
                forceMoveTo = false
                )

        }
        drawPath(
            path = path,
            style = Stroke(width = 10f),
            brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                colors = listOf(
                    Color.Red,
                    Color.Blue,)
            ),
        )
   }

}
This is the shape I was expecting

but the arc isn't appearing.
I think it has something to do with a misunderstanding of the rect parameter in the arcTo function.
I read that the left and top parameters were for the top left corner of an imaginary rectangle,
and the right and bottom parameters were for the bottom right corner.
I entered in the coordinates based on my understanding but it's still not working.

In the text you talk about a "half circle arch on the right side", but the arc in the image you used to illustrate looks more like a quarter circle. Not exactly, but certainly not a half circle.
Assuming you want exactly a quarter circle you could use this:
arcTo(
    rect = Rect(
        left = 400f,
        top = -200f,
        right = 1000f,
        bottom = 400f
    ),
    startAngleDegrees = 90f,
    sweepAngleDegrees = 90f,
    forceMoveTo = false,
)

First, think about how the full circle would look like. Since the other shape has a height of 300, the circle would need to have a height of 600. Since it's a circle and not an oval that will also be its width. Now you need to define the Rect so the circle fits in it. The left is 400 so it touches the end of the upper part of the other shape, and the bottom needs to be aligned with the lower part of the other shape, which is also 400. top and right can then be calculated by subtracting respectively adding the circle's diameter of 600.
Now, since you do not want to draw the entire circle you need to define where the segment that you want to draw should begin. That would be at the bottom right of the other shape. For the center of the circle that is looking straight down. startAngleDegrees starts with 0 at the right and going clockwise, so "straight down" will be 90 degrees. sweepAngleDegrees then defines how much of the circle's segment should be drawn. Since you want a quarter circle, that will be an additional 90 degrees.
The resulting path will be drawn like this:

With the understanding of how arcTo works you can now adapt this to what you actually want to achieve, should you want something else than a quarter circle.

I still don't understand what the rect parameters represent. Do they represent coordinators or size? The size of an imaginary box that the circle is in?

The latter. The documentation puts it like this: "the arc segment consists of the arc that follows the edge of the oval bounded by the given rectangle". That could be clearer in my opinion, but what it essentially says is that you define a rectangle which will set the bounds for the size of the oval that is drawn (in your case a circle). Instead of specifying a rectangle they could have also allowed you to specify the center coordinates of the oval and its width and height. But they decided to put it like this; so just imagine how the rectangle must look like for the entire cicle to fit in.
